# Git: Merge test repository into master repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, git-merge, git-rebase

I am new to Git/Heroku/RoR, know basics of these technologies.

- I have a git repository **repoA** which has two branches, **master** and **feature**.
- I continued working on **repoA/feature** and upon completion, because the changes were huge so decided to launch a separate app on *Heroku* to test them first.
- So deployed **repoA/feature** to **repoTest/feature** on *Heroku*. Then made some fixes to the feature and finalized the code in **repoTest/feature**.
- Another developer made some commits in **repoA/master** during this time.

Now I want to make my **repoTest/feature** LIVE and MERGE it to **repoA/master**.
Please help me how can I do that ?

*NOTE:* I have tried doing `git rebase master` but that did nothing even after a long manual conflict resolve exercise.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by the rebase did nothing.  Did the rebase ever finish?  You didn't end up ahead of master?

Comment: It finished with rebase. During the process it asked me for --continue and --skip several times for different commits. I resolved  changes manually and use --skip for unnecessary changes. Finally it ended up with the same version of repoA/master and nothing was added from feature.

Comment: when you do `git rebase master` repoA/master isn't going to change, only the branch you are currently checked out to will.  It's also unclear, but you did migrate repoTest/feature to repoA already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As below steps are my normally operations:
1. git checkout repoA/feature
2. git fetch repoTest/feature; git merge repoTest/feature repoA/feature; git stash
3. git checkout repoA/master; git pull origin
4. git checkout repoA/feature; git rebase repoA/master (maybe here you should resolve your conflicts); git stash pop
5. git status; git commit -am ""; git push origin